# How to open android default apps activity in setting via Intent?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-10.0

How to open the default handler page in the android setting via intent?
or How we can open directly the default SMS page?

[image]

it seems from android Q to upper we can not `Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT`

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer, you can open this page by this code:

```
//This code will work only on android version N and above
//Add if condition to prevent crash on older devices

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        if (requestCode != -1)
             act.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        else
             act.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with this code to open an intent default app,
in this case, I try to set the default launcher app

```
// dialog set default app
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun showLauncherSelection() {
    val roleManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ROLE_SERVICE)
            as RoleManager
    if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_HOME) &&
        !roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_HOME)
    ) {
        val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_HOME)
        startActivityForResult(intent,0)
    }
}
```

You can set the other Default app with change the `ROLE_HOME` following this [Role Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/role/RoleManager?hl=en). If you want to change SMS default app, try to change the `ROLE_HOME` to `ROLE_SMS`